# RegEx to detect blocks of indented code not including the final newline

Tags: regex

I have the following Regex to detect indented (4 spaces or a tab) blocks of code:

```
^((?:(?:    | *\t)+.*\n?)*)$
```

My issue is that while this will indeed detect blocks of code, the back reference (when I use `$1` also includes the final newline, where I'd like it to end at the end of the last line.

Here is an image showing the issue:

[image]

As you can see in the third line (with the "three" text) the highlight extends all the way to the end, indicating it matches the newline as well.

How would I tweak my Regex to account for this?

Comment: Try this one: `^((?: {4}| *\t)+\S.*)$`

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes It matches only one line.

Comment: Well, your regex is really tricky and I do not grasp the idea behind it. I have no idea what the environment is used. Without that, no serious optimization can be made. Right now, I could only come up with [`^((?:\n?(?:[ ]{4}|[\t ])+(?:(?![ ]{4}|[\t ]).)*)+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/cN1uS8/2).

Comment: @stribizhev It's used in an Objective-C environment if that helps at all (multi-line). How could I clarify my goal to you? I want to match code blocks, simply blocks with four spaces before every line, but it can't capture the newline at the end for concision purposes.

Comment: If you need to check for tabs, too, I can suggest [`^((?:\n?(?:[ ]{4}|\t)+[^\n]*)+)`](https://regex101.com/r/kX5hH7/1) (yes, use it with `multiline` flag).

Answer (score 1):

Move `\n?` to the beginning: `^((?:(?:\n?    | *\t)+.*)*)$`.

See result on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cT8uL2/1).

Comment: Looks like [it can cause catastrophic backtracking](https://regex101.com/r/cT8uL2/2) easily.

Comment: 2112 characters in one line.. I don't think it will happen.. but it is a good example

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes: You can shorten their number considerably and you will still get the issue.

Comment: @stribizhev Do you have a better solution then perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
^((?:(?:    | *\t)+.*\n?)*(?:(?:    | *\t)+.*))$
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cT8uL2/3)

Answer (score 1):

It's usually a good regex pattern to negative matching i.e. capture whilst not new line:

```
((?:^(?:[ ]{4}|\t)(?:[^\r\n]*))+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

https://regex101.com/r/fH4mD5/5